# Javascript being mysterious again?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a service in angular which has two properties that are same type. I push same objects in a reverse order to them for testing. But When I change one of the objects in one array I see that same code changes same object in the second array too. The thing is I don't even mention the second array in the code. Here is my service class :

```
class Myservice {

  public meetings : Meeting [];
  public participated : Meeting [];

  constructor(){
      this.meeting = [];
      this.participated = [];
  }

  create(participants, id){

       let meeting : Meeting = {
          id : id,
          participants : participants
       }

      this.meetings.push(meeting);
      this.participated.unshift(meeting);
  }

  addParticipant(userId : number, meetingId : number){
      this.meetings.forEach((meeting : Meeting) => { 
         if(meeting.id == meetingId)  {
           meeting.participants.push(userId)
         } 
      })
  }


}
```

My Meeting Interface :

```
interface Meeting {
     id : number;
     participants : Array<number>;
}
```

This How I test it :

```
describe('My service', () => {

     let provider : Myservice;

     beforeEach( () => {
        provider = new Myservice();
     });

     it('should add a participant to the participants', () => {

        provider.create([2], 1);
        provider.create([2], 2);
        provider.create([2], 3);
        provider.create([2], 4);

        provider.addParticipant(6, 3);

        expect(provider.meetings[2].participants).toEqual([2,6])  
        //expect(provider.participated[1].participants).toEqual([2,6])  

        console.log('meeting par :', provider.meetings[2].participants)
        console.log('Partic par :', provider.participated[1].participants)
     })
```

This test passes as It should but logs says that:

```
LOG: 'meeting par :', [2, 6]
LOG: 'Partic par :', [2, 6]
```

As we see the object in the participated array also changed :O. Do you guys have any idea why ? My karma/jasmine versions are :

```
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
"@types/node": "^12.0.4",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"core-js": "^3.1.3",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
"jasmine": "^3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
"null-loader": "^2.0.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"ts-loader": "^3.0.3",
"ts-node": "^3.0.2",
"typescript": "~2.6.2"
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
```

Edit. New form of `create` function also giving the same response:

```
  create(participants, id){
      this.meetings.push({
         id : id,
         participants : participants
      });
      this.participated.unshift({
         id : id,
         participants : participants
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing the same object by it's reference to both arrays. That's the cause of your problem. You should either create a new object for each push or clone the object.

### Update #1

The second potential problem I've found is your `participants` array.

In JS arrays as well as objects are passed by reference when are simply assigned.

For simple objects you may use `Object.assign` and for simple arrays `[..].slice()`.

Another way of cloning is
`var a = {...myObj}` for objects and `var b = [...myArr]` for arrays.

Those methods are for simple cloning which won't clone nested objects/arrays properly. For that sake you would need to write a recursive cloning function or use `cloneDeep` from Lodash which is both compatible with arrays and objects.

Comment: Thanks for response but did not work. I created another meeting object with same values and pushed to second array. Result did not change.

Comment: @AkilDemir may you provide us with StackBlitz example or similar angular playground?

Comment: @AkilDemir have you cloned the `participants` array? Array is like object is passed by reference when you just assign it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xb6dg I am not familiar with those playgrounds but did my best.

Comment: sorry didn't understand the cloning the array part. can you please explain more?

Comment: Yea the problem was in the cloning the array. `Object.assign` doesn't clone the array in the object. Everything is ok now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, looking at your code:

```
create(participants, id){
  let meeting : Meeting = {
    id : id,
    participants : participants
  }

  this.meetings.push(meeting);
  this.participated.unshift(meeting);
}
```

You are creating *one* object, and pushing that one object into two different places. When you are pushing these objects into these arrays, you are giving these arrays not a copy of the object, but a reference to it.

In memory, only one `meeting` exist, and it has a reference inside the `meetings` and the `participated` arrays. So when you get the `meeting` inside of `addParticipant`, you are modifying that one and only `meeting` object.

It's not JavaScript being mysterious, think of it as the arrays having a reference to the object, not the object themselves.

Additionally, the `participants` array is also the object with two references. If you want a copy of the array to be on each instance, you can spread it in a new array. An example of copying an array using the spread syntax, and how to use the spread syntax in arrays, can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals).

To solve this, you can create a new object every time you push to an array, while spreading the participants array into a new one to create a new array of participants:

```
  this.meetings.push({id: id, participants: [...participants]});
  this.participated.unshift({id: id, participants: [...participants]});
```

Or, you can use the object literal shorthand since they use the same names for the `id` property:

```
  this.meetings.push({id, participants: [...participants]});
  this.participated.unshift({id, participants: [...participants]});
```

That way, each array has a reference to a distinct object, and each `participants` array is also unique within the `Meeting` object.

Hope that helps!

**Edit 1:** added additional details after finding more than one issue with the code provided

**Edit 2:** added resources on the spread operator, and using it on arrays

Comment: Thanks but did not work.I tried  `this.meetings.push({id: id, participants: [...participants]});` and pushed the arrays separately but I got same response. I also tried to clone the object with `Object.assign` got the same response.

Comment: Interesting... Could you post the new code for the `create` function?

Comment: It seems that you did not clone the array in the update. If you look closely at the example code, when assigning the array to the participants property, you _spread_ it into a new array:  `this.meetings.push({id, participants: [...participants]});`. The important part there is the square brackets and the three periods. You can see an example and read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals

Comment: Yea. you are right. I was cloning the object even with `Object.assign`, it wasn't cloning the array too. Everything is as expected now. Thank you.